# Show that this Markov chain is recurrent or transient

Tags: proof-verification, markov-chains

> > Consider the Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ with state space $E=\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}$ and transition matrix
> >     $$
> > T=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
> > $$
> >     Is this Markov Chain recurrent or transient?

First of all, it is to say that this Markov chain is irreducible, i.e. only has one communicating class $C=E$. Because recurrence and transience are class properties, it sufficies to examine for example whether$\mathbb{P}_1(t(1)<\infty):=\mathbb{P}(t(1)<\infty|X_0=1)=1$ (in which case the MC would be recurrent) or $\mathbb{P}_1(t(1)<\infty)<1$ (in which case the MC would be transient)}.
Here for $i\in E$ it is 
$$
t\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{+\infty\right\}, t(\omega):=\inf\left\{n\in\mathbb{N}: X_n(\omega)=i\right\}.
$$

Another way to examine this is to look whether
$$
\mathbb{P}_1(\left\{\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: X_n=i\right\})=1
$$
or
$$
\mathbb{P}_1(\left\{\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: X_n=i\right\})<1.
$$

I think I should use this. So set $A:=\left\{\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: X_n=1\right\}$. Then it is $\mathbb{P}_1(A)=$
\begin{align}
&\mathbb{P}_1(A,X_1=2)+\mathbb{P}_1(A,X_1=3)\\
&\geq\mathbb{P}_1(X_1=2,X_2=4,X_3=1)+\mathbb{P}_1(X_1=2,X_2=5,X_3=1)+\mathbb{P}_1(X_1=3,X_2=4,X_3=1)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(X_1=2,X_2=4,X_3=1|X_0=1)+\mathbb{P}(X_1=2,X_2=5,X_3=1|X_0=1)+\mathbb{P}(X_1=3,X_2=4,X_3=1|X_0=1)\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_0=1,X_1=2,X_2=4,X_3=1)}{\mathbb{P}(X_0=1)}+\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_0=1,X_1=2,X_2=5,X_3=1)}{\mathbb{P}(X_0=1)}+\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_0=1,X_1=3,X_2=4,X_3=1)}{\mathbb{P}(X_0=1)}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_0=1)p_{12}p_{24}p_{41}}{\mathbb{P}(X_0=1)}+\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_0=1)p_{12}p_{25}p_{51}}{\mathbb{P}(X_0=1)}+\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_0=1)p_{13}p_{34}p_{41}}{\mathbb{P}(X_0=1)}\\
&=p_{12}p_{24}p_{41}+p_{12}p_{25}p_{51}+p_{13}p_{34}p_{41}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1
\end{align}

So it follows that
$$
\mathbb{P}_1(A)=1,
$$
meaning that the Markov chain is recurrent.

Am I right?
Is my "strategy" okay?

Comment: This Markov chain has a stationary distribution (it's uniform on $E$), so every state is recurrent. An irreducible Markov chain with a finite state space is always recurrent.

Comment: Does from stationary distribution follow that it is recurrent?

Comment: I don't think having a stationary distribution necessarily means the chain is recurrent. Consider the chain with transition matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\1&0\end{array}\right]$. The stationary distribution is $[1, 0]$. One state will never be recur.

Comment: But why did you write then: "This Markov chain has a stationary distribution, so every state is recurrent."?

Comment: Good question! I must have been mistaken in that first statement. I was probably thinking about the fact that every state has a positive probability in the stationary distribution and therefore a finite expected return time and therefore is positive recurrent.